# Regex to replace tags content

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with this code:

```
$message='<ha>hello</ha>';
$message = str_replace('<ha>(.*?)</ha>', '<ha>bye</ha>', $message);
echo $message;
```

The output is still hello although i want it to be bye..It might be simple but I am using regex for first time.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `str_replace()` !== `preg_replace()`

Comment: `str_replace` doesn't do regex. Did you mean [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)?

Comment: can you suggest the regex to use with preg_replace() with this one

Comment: When you switch to `preg_replace` don't forget to add delimiters. Your regex is correct. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php If you don't care about what was found you can take the grouping off your regex. Note the `$1` that's just in case you did group this for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` function:

```
$message='<ha>hello</ha>';
$message = preg_replace('/<ha>(.*?)<\/ha>/', '<ha>bye</ha>', $message);
echo $message; // gives: <ha>bye</ha>
```

Demo:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b0a2239a891223472e93f8a362e5946e5719df0